# Constructing a table from raw data in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am frustrated beyond belief with Powershell at the moment, because I feel stupid for spending 2 whole work days figuring out a (most likely super simple) solution for the following problem: I would like to convert two arrays (`$HeaderCells`, `$DataCells`) into a table and nothing seems to work. I tried PSObjects, Arrays, Hash Tables, data tables... Here is my code:

```
$Table = @()
$HeaderCells = @("Company","Country")
$DataCells = @("Test Inc.","Misc Corp.","USA","UK")

foreach ($HeaderCell in $HeaderCells)
{
    foreach ($DataCell in $DataCells)
    {
        $Table += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{$HeaderCell=$DataCell}
    }
}
$Table
```

my Output is:

```
Company   
-------   
Test Inc. 
USA       
Misc Corp.
UK
```

I would like to get two columns (Company and Country), but no matter what I try (even the most nested for loops, I always end up overwriting variables or just getting errors.

My actual use case is actually a bit more complicated (extracting a table from a html page), but solving this part will allow me to continue, I hope.

My desired output would be to have the HeaderCells as the Headers and the DataCells as the Rows, so something like this:

```
Company     Country
-------           --------
Test Inc.       USA 
Misc Corp.  UK
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? How do you assign a data cell to its header? Or do you want to have all four data cells at each header?

Comment: I've edited my post and included my desired output. Thanks for pointing out that that was missing!

Comment: Every child knows what's a company and what's a country, but how should the program knew? There must be some sort of rule to define whats should be added to companies, and what to countries.

Comment: Well, that is kind of the reason for me asking the question. I've tried many solutions to assign the $HeaderCells array as the column name and the $DataCells array as the values. I thought someone might have an idea for a routine that implements that exact logic since I've run out of ideas how to accomplish this. It should be possible, since headers and data cells are clearly defined, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume you already have a way to populate `$HeaderCells` and `$DataCells` with collections, you could take a more dynamic approach:

```
$DataCountPerGroup = $DataCells.Count/$HeaderCells.Count

$table = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DataCountPerGroup; $i++) {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    $dataIncrement = 0
    $HeaderCells | Foreach-Object { 
        $index = $dataIncrement * $DataCountPerGroup
        $hash.Add($_,$DataCells[$i+$index])
        $dataIncrement++
    }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
}
$table
```

This assumes that `$DataCells.Count % $HeaderCells.Count` is `0` and if not, you will need some error checking.

The idea is if you have `n` number of headers, then you will have `n` category groups of data with each of those having the exact same number of items.

The outer `for` loops through the number of items in a data category. This means if you have 4 companies (category 1), 4 countries (category 2), and 4 websites (category 3), the loop will iterate 0 through 3 (4 times). An ordered hash table is initialized at the beginning of the loop. `$dataIncrement` is a temporary variable to help us jump from the different categories within `$DataCells`. Once the hash table is populated, it can then be used to construct the custom object that will represent an entry in your table (`$table`).

---

A trivial example using the indices of your two arrays would process as follows:

1. `$HeaderCells` contains 3 items (indexes 0-2)
2. `$DataCells` contains 15 items (3 groups of 5 items)(indexes 0-14)
3. `$i` becomes `0`.
4. `$hash` is initialized.
5. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[0]` and value `$DataCells[0]`.
6. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[1]` and value `$DataCells[5]`.
7. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[2]` and value `$DataCells[10]`.
8. A custom object is created using `$hash` and is added to `$table`.
9. `$i` becomes `1`.
10. `$hash` is initialized.
11. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[0]` and value `$DataCells[1]`.
12. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[1]` and value `$DataCells[6]`.
13. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[2]` and value `$DataCells[11]`.
14. A custom object is created using `$hash` and is added to `$table`.
15. `$i` becomes `2`.
16. `$hash` is initialized.
17. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[0]` and value `$DataCells[2]`.
18. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[1]` and value `$DataCells[7]`.
19. `$hash` adds key `$HeaderCells[2]` and value `$DataCells[12]`.
20. A custom object is created using `$hash` and is added to `$table`.
21. By now, you can see the repeated processes that are happening. `$i` will continue to increment and the processes will continue with the same pattern until `$i` becomes `5`. When `$i` becomes `5`, the processing will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what data you want to sort out there, but look at the example bellow. Basically I am creating a `[PSCustomObject]` and attach that as a row of an array.

```
$list=@(
    "Apple Corp",
    "Peach LLC",
    "Ananas LLC",
    "Tomato Corp"
)

$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($name in $list){

    if($name -like "*corp"){
        $obj=[pscustomobject]@{
            Company = $name
            Country = 'USA'
        }
        $result += $obj
    }else{
        $obj=[pscustomobject]@{
            Company = $name
            Country = 'UK'
        }
        $result += $obj
    }
}
```

And the here is the output :

```
Write-Output $result

Company     Country
-------     -------
Apple Corp  USA    
Peach LLC   UK     
Ananas LLC  UK     
Tomato Corp USA
```

This is just PoC to get the idea, the logic you want to implement is all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your example data, but here's how you might structure the code if your data was tweaked a bit to have a repeated list of [company1], [country1], [company2], [country2], etc.

```
$HeaderCells = @("Company","Country")
$DataCells = @("Test Inc.","USA","Misc Corp.","UK", "Canada Post", "CA")

$Table = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DataCells.Count; ) {

    $row = new-object -TypeName PSObject

    # Suggestion to replace the following:
    #   foreach ($HeaderCell in $HeaderCells)
    #   {
    #     $row | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $HeaderCell -Value $DataCells[ $i++ ]
    #   }
    # with:
    $HeaderCells | ForEach-Object { 
        $row | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value $DataCells[ $i++ ]
    }
    $Table += $row
}

$Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
$DataCells = "Test Inc.","Misc Corp.","USA","UK"
$half = [math]::Floor($DataCells.Count / 2)

(0..($half - 1)) | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Company = $DataCells[$_]
        Country = $DataCells[$_ + $half]
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Company    Country
> -------    -------
> Test Inc.  USA    
> Misc Corp. UK
> ```